# Формат даты Java

Tags: java, дата

```
SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")
```

Почему здесь - 2 `d` (`dd`) и 2 `M` - `MM`?
Что было бы, если бы было указано `d.M.yyyy`?

Answer (score 4):

В случае использования формата `dd` первое число месяца, например, будет показываться как `01`. В случае использования `d`, будет `1`. В [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) даже пример есть.